# Machine learning concepts confusion

Tags: machine-learning

Can someone explain following four machine learning problems:

1. binary classification,
2. regression,
3. multiple independent binary classification, and
4. 1-of-K multiclass classification.

Please use set and numerical domain notation to denote the input and output spaces of each problem. Quite confused at these concepts. When I try to search that in Wikipedia, I think the answers are not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, most problems in machine learning are of two types :

## Classification, and Regression.

Imagine yourself as the owner of an apple orchard. You produce many different varieties of apples every year, but you face two problems : rotten apples, and demand forecasting (you don't know how much to stock,transport for improving profit).

For the first problem, where we find rotten apples out of all produced apples, to be thrown out, this is a "Binary classification problem"

But suppose, you want to separate all varieties of apples, before dispatching them, you are looking at a "Multi-Class Classification Problem"

So, a classification problem can be defined as follows :

Given a set of tuples $(x_i,y_i)$, where $x_i \in D$, $y_i \in  \{1,2,3 ... n\}$, with $n$ denoting number of classes, (although $y_i$ can be any finite set, we choose integers for convenience), find an element $y_j \in  \{1,2,3 ... n\} $ for an $x_j \in D$, such that you optimize some given error function.

Binary classification is a special case of the above with $n=2$

The "method" or the mathematical model that you adopt to find $y_j$ given $x_j$ is called the classifier, which we will denote by $C$.

## One-of-K Classification :

So instead of using a single classifier to tell you what category $x_j$ belongs to, if we use multiple classifiers $C_i$s such that each $C_i$ gives you $Pr(y_j=i|x_j)$, is a one-vs-all classifier. This is also called one-of-K classification by some texts.

You could then take the decision of these classifiers and choose the class with maximum probability and so on.

In essence , you take an apple, and $C_j$ tells you if it belongs to variety $j$

## Multiple independent(?) binary classifier

Another way to do this, is as follows. We could use $C(n,2) = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ classifiers, with C being the combinatorial "choose" function, with each classifier $c_ij$, deciding just between categories $i,j$.

You run a sample through all the $C(n,2)$ and decide which variety it could belong to, like a round robin tournament. This method is sometimes called the multiple independent binary classifier, since each classifier only works with two classes, and outputs of any two different classifiers are statistically uncorrelated.

(I am not really sure if they are independent, and I have never heard of this specific name)

## Regression :

So now that you have all healthy apples binned into different categories, you want to know how much of each variety to deliver to each shop, a natural way would be to deliver depending on the average requirements.

Regression is the process of associating an input $x_i \in D$ to a vector $y \in R^n$ , (n could also be one), while trying to minimize some error function.

The basic difference between classification and regression is that, the output set of classification is necessarily finite, while it usually is a continuous space for regression.